# Insert .so file into common-auth file on unix

Tags: linux, unix, authentication, centos, pam

I want to create secondary authentication for my ubuntu. I created one pam module for that. Now i want to run on my os using their .so file. So can i insert it into common-auth file or other file. and where is I save this .so to use authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your tag `centos` and `ubuntu` in the question, I am a little confused, but I assume the procedure wouldn't be too different between the two for `pam`. Here are some suggestions for `centos`.

You can create your own auth file in `/etc/pam.d/`. File names in here normally represent a service or daemon, e.g., `crond` and/or `sshd`.

`.so` pam modules should go into `/lib64/secutiry/`. This directory is owned by the `pam` package and get read by the auth files.

```
$ cat /etc/pam.d/sshd 
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required pam_sepermit.so
auth       include      password-auth
....
....
```